# Determine how to evaluate missing data variables properly in a function that uses '{{'

Tags: r, r-highcharter, tidyeval

I'm attempting to build a function to produce box plots via `highcharter`. Once upon a time a function existed in highcharter called `hcboxplot` which has since been deprecated and which also uses deprecated tidy functions at this point.

Therefore, I'm now using `highcharter::data_to_boxplot` which creates a data.frame with list columns where each list includes boxplot.stats points. In an effort to simplify things for my team and I; I want to write a wrapper function for data_to_boxplot that builds out a basic boxplot.

Since `data_to_boxplot` uses *data variables* I need to embrace -> {{}} my arguments in order to evaluate them in the right context. Maybe there's another way? I'm very new to tidy evaluation as I mainly work with `data.table` and am having difficulty with handling optional parameters.

#### Example output:

```
library(data.table)
library(highcharter)
library(tidyr)

# dummy data
tmp = data.table(
  x1 = runif(30) * 10,
  grp = rep(c("a","b","c"),10),
  grp2 = rep(c("d","e"),15)
)

# transformed for hc
stat = data_to_boxplot(tmp, x1, grp, grp2)

# sample plot
highchart(type = "chart") %>%
  hc_add_series_list(stat)
```

#### Issue - when using a wrapper:

```
hc_boxplot = function(data, x, var = NULL, var2 = NULL, outliers = FALSE, ...) {
  arggs = list(...)

  d = data_to_boxplot(data = data, variable = {{x}}, group_var = {{var}}, group_var2 = {{var2}}, add_outliers = outliers, arggs)
  
  # basic chart
  highchart(type = "chart") %>%
    hc_add_series_list(d)
}

hc_boxplot(data = tmp, x = x1, var = grp, name = "test")
# Error in setnames(x, value) : - This refers to the excluded var2 arg
# Can't assign 1 names to a 0 column data.table
```

This works for the most part when all arguments are used but if I omit `var2` or `var & var2`. Those args are still evaluated using {{}} even though to my understanding they should be missing. Below is a snippet from the data_to_boxplot code where the wrong portion of the if statement is evaluated. Since data_to_boxplot doesn't treat var2 as missing.

```
# where var2 == group_var2
# evaluates to TRUE instead of FALSE and proceeds to build an empty table
  if (!missing(group_var2)) { 
    dg2 <- data %>% select({
      {
        group_var2
      }
    })
  }
  else {
    dg2 <- data.frame(rep(NA, nrow(dx)))
  }
```

Since the arguments are not environment variables, I'm wondering how I can signal to data_to_boxplot in my wrapper that the omitted arguments are in fact missing.

---

Additionally, I'm having trouble passing in named arguments via (...) to data_to_boxplot. In my example above I use `name = "test"` which should name the series but am getting an undesired result. Where a new column is added named "arggs" with "test" in it instead of updated the column titled "name".

```
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  name  data       id    type    arggs       
  <chr> <list>     <chr> <chr>   <named list>
1 d     <list [3]> d     boxplot <chr [1]>   
2 e     <list [3]> e     boxplot <chr [1]>
```

Appreciate any help on this as I'm sufficiently stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in highcharter. They are currently using this pattern in `data_to_boxplot()`:

```r
if (!missing(group_var)) {
  dg <- data %>% select({{ group_var }})
}
```

But using `missing()` on arguments that might contain `{{` doesn't work. What they should do instead:

```r
# Defuse `group_var` into a quosure so we can inspect it
group_var <- enquo(group_var)

# Inspect the defused quosure with `quo_is_missing()`
if (!quo_is_missing(group_var)) {
  # Inject it back into the data-masking expression
  dg <- data %>% select(!!group_var)
}
```

Until this is fixed upstream, you can work around. This is not so trivial because missing values are involved:

```r
hc_boxplot = function(data, x, var, var2, outliers = FALSE, ...) {
  arggs = list(...)

  # Capture defused expressions so we can inspect them and remove
  # missing values
  defused_args = enquos(
    variable = x,
    group_var = var,
    group_var2 = var2
  )

  # Remove any missing arguments
  defused_args = Filter(\(x) !rlang::quo_is_missing(x), defused_args)

  # We'll inject the compacted list of defused expressions with `!!!`
  # back into `data_to_boxplot()`. This is equivalent to using
  # `do.call()` for a list of arguments.  In data-masking functions,
  # only `...` supports `!!!` automatically. To use it on named
  # arguments like `variable` and `group_var1`, we need to explicitly
  # enable `!!!` with `inject()`.
  d = inject(
    data_to_boxplot(
      data,
      !!!defused_args,
      add_outliers = outliers,
      !!!arggs
    )
  )

  # basic chart
  highchart(type = "chart") %>%
    hc_add_series_list(d)
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help on this. Months later, I've decided I want to pass in variables and not just data col names. So in the above function instead of `hc_boxplot(data, x = x1, ...)` I now need the flexibility for `hc_boxplot(data, x = !!variable, ...)` where `variable = "x1"`. My solution for this is to check if the quosure is not a symbol, if not then convert to a symbol. Do you think this is an appropriate approach? Below is my code chunk for it. Appreciate the help on this.

Comment: `# Determine if any args are not symbols e.g. a string and set them to be a symbol
  defused_args = lapply(defused_args, function(x) {
    if(!rlang::quo_is_symbol(x)) {
      x = rlang::quo_set_expr(x, sym(quo_name(x)))
    }
    return(x)
  })`